# How do I prevent Docker from source NAT'ing traffic on Synology NAS

Tags: docker, iptables, synology

On a Synology NAS, it appears the default setup for docker/iptables is to source NAT traffic going to the container to the gateway IP.  This fundamentally causes problems when the container needs to see the correct/real client IP. I do not see this issue when running on an ubuntu system, for example.

Let me walk you though what I'm seeing.  On the Synology NAS, I'll run a simple nginx container:

```
docker run --rm -ti -p 80:80 nginx
```

(I have [disabled the Synology NAS from using port 80](https://www.reddit.com/r/synology/comments/ahs3xh/prevent_dsm_listening_on_port_80443/))

I'll do a curl from my laptop and I see the following log line:

```
172.17.0.1 - - [05/May/2020:17:02:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "curl/7.64.1" "-"
```

Hm... the client IP (`172.17.0.1`) is the `docker0` interface on the NAS.

```
user@synology:~$ ifconfig docker0
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:B5:BE:C5:51
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          <snip>
```

When I first saw this, I was quite confused because I did not recall docker networking working this way.  So I fired up my ubuntu VM and tried the same test (same docker run command from earlier).

The log line from my curl test off box:

```
172.16.207.1 - - [05/May/2020:17:12:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "curl/7.64.1" "-"
```

In this case the `docker0` IP was not the source of the traffic as seen by the container.

```
user@ubuntu-vm:~# ifconfig docker0
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        <snip>
```

So it appears that the docker network setup for a Synolgy NAS is different vs a more standard ubuntu deployment. Okay, neat.  So how does one fix this?

This is where I'm struggling. Clearly something is happening with iptables. Running the same `iptables -t nat -L -n` command on both systems shows vastly different results.

```
user@synology:~$ iptables -t nat -L -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DEFAULT_OUTPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DEFAULT_POSTROUTING  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DEFAULT_OUTPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain DEFAULT_POSTROUTING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:80

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:172.17.0.2:80
```

```
user@ubuntu-vm:~# iptables -t nat -L -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.18.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:80

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:172.17.0.2:80
```

I do not really understand how these chains work or why they're different for different systems. I haven't changed any docker level settings on either system, these are default configs.

Has anyone ran into this before?  Is there a quick way to toggle this?

Answer (score 4):

I've experienced this issue myself while using Pi-hole (described [here](https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/issues/135#issuecomment-614724181)) and this iptables rule seems to fix it:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
```

Be aware that this is not permanent, so if you reboot the NAS you will have to apply it again.

---

**Update:** Here's a more "permanent" fix: https://gist.github.com/PedroLamas/db809a2b9112166da4a2dbf8e3a72ae9