# The server receiving the HTTP request identifies the IP address of the container instead of the server's IP address

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, dockerfile, ip

There is a Nginx container that belongs to the `messaging` microservice written **in Laravel** with IP `172.19.0.8` in a server. The container inside the server posts an HTTP request to another server. However, the destination server identifies the IP address of the requester as `172.19.0.8`  not the IP address of the server.

I already saw [How to make Docker container see real user IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537954/how-to-make-docker-container-see-real-user-ip) and the question is different. The cause of the problem given the link was setting the firewall, while there is no firewall in my server (still a test server and configured yet). I also make an HTTP request to another server and I have no access to that.

This is the docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

networks:
  common_network:
    external: true
  messaging_network:
    name: messaging_network
    driver: bridge

services:
  messaging_php:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php8.1.Dockerfile
      args:
        uid: "${UID-1000}"
        gid: "${GID-1000}"
    container_name: "messaging_php"
    image: messaging_php
    restart: always
    tty: true
    networks:
      - messaging_network
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "${MESSAGING_PHP_PORT}:9000"
  messaging_nginx:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile
    container_name: messaging_nginx
    image: messaging_nginx
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${MESSAGING_NGINX_PORT}:80"
    networks:
      - messaging_network
      - common_network
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - messaging_php
  messaging_mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.26
    container_name: messaging_mysql
    restart: always
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "${MESSAGING_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
        SERVICE_TAGS: "messaging"
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
    networks:
      - messaging_network

volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
```

This is `nginx.Docerfile`

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

and `default.conf`

```
server {
    resolver 127.0.0.11;
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    client_max_body_size 64M;

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }



    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass messaging_php:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;

    }
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/services/reverse_proxy.conf;
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

and `nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout           50000;
    proxy_connect_timeout       60000;
    proxy_send_timeout          60000;
    send_timeout                60000;
    client_max_body_size        50000;
    client_header_timeout       60000;
    client_body_timeout         60000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout        30000;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

How can I fix the problem so that it finds the IP of the server, not the container?

Comment: That is normal behaviour. Have Nginx add information to the request about who the request was forwarded for, so you can get that information. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/

Comment: @HansKilian I added the NGINX configurations. Can you provide more specific and detailed guidance?

Comment: Please include more detail than "it didn't work" so this can be reopened.

Comment: @BMitch I was going to start a bounty but you closed it!

Comment: "the problem given the link was setting the firewall, while there is no firewall in my server", that's very unlikely to be correct. Docker depends on iptables, and without it, the install will typically fail. The linked question has an answer for redhat based systems, but there would be a similar answer for debian based platforms using iptables commands. To understand how the questions may be different, I'm looking for a network diagram of the various nodes and containers, the IP addresses of each, the flow of the request, and which node sees which IP.

Comment: @BMitch I followed each step suggested by that link, but it didn't work. I explicitly mentioned that my project is based on Laravel. I really don't understand your insistence on closing my question.